# Hibernate AnnotationException unknown entity on Enum

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums

I want to assign different Roles to Users for every Organization they work in. I got the idea for the entity GrantedRole from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602386/mapping-value-in-junction-table-to-entity/).

However, when I try to run my unit tests, they all fail on loading the application context, because Hibernate can't find the entity Role. GrantedRole is added to my persistence.xml.
The error that I get is:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
> com.onior.modm.registration.domain.GrantedRole.role references an
> unknown entity: com.onior.modm.registration.domain.GrantedRole$Role

When I add GrantedRole.Role to persistence.xml as well I get:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> modm-persistence] class or package not found
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.onior.modm.registration.domain.GrantedRole.Role

My code for GrantedRole, I left out the setters. DomainEntity is a superclass for all my entities.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_assignments", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "user", "organization"}))
public class GrantedRole extends DomainEntity implements GrantedAuthority {

    private User user;
    private Role role;
    private Organization organization;
    
    public enum Role {
        USER, ORGADMIN, ADMIN
    }

    public GrantedRole() {
        super();
    }
    
    public GrantedRole(User user, Role role, Organization organization) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
```

What do I do to solve this? I would prefer keeping Role as en enum, or at least not make it an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, I think I know what's going wrong. I declared GrantedRole-Role as a ManyToOne relation, but that expects Role to be an Entity, which it isn't. I removed the `@ManyToOne` part, and everything works as expected now :)

Turns out I should have spent just a half hour longer on reading through blog posts and SO questions before posting a new question...